# How to get window ID from process ID

Tags: process, xdotool

This command will get the PID of the `xterm` process launched:

```
xterm & export APP_PID=$!
```

How can I get the window ID associated to that process (the `xterm` window ID)? I mean, the ID that `xdotool selectwindow` would return after clicking on the `xterm` window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's been discussed in the "other" forum:

- [Is there a linux command to determine the window IDs associated with a given process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250757/is-there-a-linux-command-to-determine-the-window-ids-associated-with-a-given-pro)
- [How to get an X11 Window from a Process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151407/how-to-get-an-x11-window-from-a-process-id)

In the first, [@Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2250879/4518274) points out that [`xwininfo`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xwininfo&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3) can return information on *all* windows, and by using [`xprop`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xprop&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SuSE%20Linux%2Fi386%2011.3&arch=default&format=html) for each window, you can check for the `_NET_WM_PID` property, matching it against your process-id.

Comment: The most direct way, as given in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2754512/5008284) in your 2nd link, is `win=$(sed -zn < /proc/$APP_PID/environ  's/^WINDOWID=\(.*\)/\1/p')`

Comment: sure - if you prefer non-portable answers.

Comment: It's worth noting `WINDOWID` is a *terminal emulator convention* (probably from `xterm` in X10R4, 1986, yes X10, not a typo) not a general X application one; like `_NET_WM_PID` is a wm-spec convention (since a 1999 draft) that not all terminals follow. Even some modern terminal emulators don't always set `WINDOWID`. It is also the case that non-terminal processes can inherit it via a parent shell. Beware poking in `environ` files ;-)

Comment: yes, but OP didn't ask that (xterm implements that, too [see notes](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_203)).

Answer (score 17):

You can get the list of matching windows via

```
 xdotool search --pid [pid]
```

also see `xdotool help search`

Answer (score 10):

I will use this simple command to get the window ID in hex format

```
wmctrl -l | grep -i xterm | awk '{print $1}'
```

For decimal format, `bc` command can be used for conversion

```
echo "ibase=16; `wmctrl -l | grep -i xterm | cut -c 3-11 | tr a-z A-Z`" | bc
```

Comment: `wmctrl -l` doesn't give useful results if your xterm window title has been set, e.g., to a string which does not contain "xterm".

Comment: There are options you can add. `-p` gives PID, `-G` gives position and dimensions. In my case, `wmctrl -l -p | { pidof firefox vlc | read line && grep ${line// /\\|} }`, and optionally go straight for xwininfo from there: `| while read id junk; do xwininfo -id $id; done`. I'm using zsh, I'm not sure if that regex is fully portable.