# Maximizing a window (Keepassx2) from command line

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, i3, maximize, keepassx

I'm using `i3wm` and Keepassx2 on an Arch-Linux installation. I configured `i3` to automatically move a window with the window class `"Keepassx2"` to a certain workspace `$WSKP`. I also configured `$mod+P` to execute `Keepassx2`. Now I would like to write a custom script that is executed by `$mod+P` instead. This script should:

- launch `Keepassx2` when no other instance of it is currently running
- maximize `Keepassx2` and move focus to the specific workspace `$WSKP` when there already is a running instance

I want this because I don't need the Keepass-Workspace to be open all the time and it takes another unnecessary keypress when tabbing through the workspaces.

Checking whether there already is a running instance is easy:

```
if [ $(pidof keepassx2) ]; then 
    # maximize the running instance and move focus with i3-msg
fi;
```

But how do I accomplish maximizing the running instance?

Comment: If `Keepassx2` is running in its own workspace, isn't it maximized anyway?

Comment: I forgot to add that - I would like to have it minimized per default so that it does not take up a workspace. Only when I need it.

Comment: You cannot minimize or maximize a window in i3. Use tabbed mode. i3 has a hidden workspace to hide windows: https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_scratchpad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i3 has no 'maximize' function, you want to focus your window and you might want to make the window fullscreen.

You can use this snipped:

```
winid="$(printf "%u\n" $windowid 2>/dev/null)
i3-msg "[id=\"$winid\"] "focus; fullscreen"
```

How you get the `windowid` from the pid is described [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321079/how-to-get-window-id-from-process-id).