# Get Window ID from PID [Wayland and X]

Tags: process, wayland

I saw [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321079/how-to-get-window-id-from-process-id) here and wanted to know if there's any way to also implement the same idea - getting Window ID from PID in Wayland (or preferably, something that is protocol agnostic). X has `xdotool` and various other tools (e.g. `xwininfo`, `xprop`, `wlmctrl`) to handle this, but there is no current alternative that can do this on Wayland or both X/Wayland.

`proc/PID/environ` looks promising, but the fact that it is a bit finicky with the permissions makes it impractical.

If anyone has any other ideas or has done this already, that would be great. Thanks!